# TouchID suddenly stopped working

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, touch-id

Today the TouchID on my MacBook Air suddenly stopped working. Based on [this Apple's page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212225), I tried all of the steps, including wiping the sensor, different fingers, restart, adding another one, etc.

None of them work. The problem is that the sensor seems no longer detecting the fingerprint. I removed one and tried to add a new fingerprint, but it did not recognize my finger.

My MacBook Air is 2020 model with M1 chip, so SMC reset does not work, either.

Is there anything that I can do to fix the problem?
The city I'm currently in has no Apple Store.

---

#### UPDATE

This happened again, and it seems something is wrong on the software.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the this forum](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/touchid-unresponsive-on-macbook-pro-m1.2273466/), one user got an answer from an Apple technical adviser over the phone, with the following solution.

> Ok on the phone with Apple here is what they told me to do.
>
> 1. Delete all fingerprints and reset the system manager.
>    After deleting the fingerprints in the system settings, shut down the computer by choosing shut down. Better not use the touch id button.
>    CLOSE the lid of your macbook. Wait ten seconds.

> 2. open the lid and after the computer restarts, don't login but choose shut down again. Not using id touch.

> 3. Wait 30 seconds (use a timer) the lid does not need to be closed this time.

> 4. After 30 seconds restart your computer by pressing the touch id button and holding it. When you see 'options' and your Mac Hard Disc, select your HD by clicking on it while pressing 'SHIFT'. It will now be able to start up in 'Safe Mode'. Log in to your computer and give in your fingerprint in the system settings.
>    When ready:

> Restart your computer.

> I believe that this is really working but I only know for sure after a day or three.

I tried it and now my TouchID started working again.

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone who runs into this, it turned out for me that it was my standing desk power grommet that was causing static interference. Plugged into the wall with the provided adapter or running on battery it worked fine.

Comment: Exactly same here: I realized Touch ID will only work like 3 out of 10 times while connected to a non-original power source, but as soon as I disconnect it or use the original charger, it works 100%.

Note: I was using the original MagSafe cable, with a non-Apple adapter.